# How to close a gtk window and open another (python)

Tags: python, window, gtk, destroy

How to close a gtk window and open another (python)? I tried something like this:

```
gtk.main_quit()                    #or window.destroy()
os.system("./script.py")           #there is working code with gtk window in it
```

but the first window doesn't close.
I can't find a right solution anywhere. Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Can't you use [`gtkWidget.hide_all`](http://pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwidget.html#method-gtkwidget--hide-all) and hide the window and use [`gtkWidget.show_all`](http://pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwidget.html#method-gtkwidget--show-all) to show the contents of the new window?

Answer (score 0):

The `gtk.main_quit()` will cause your application to exit, it's equivalent to writing:

```
print('some line')
exit(0)
print('some other line which will never get printed')
```

Instead you should first hide the window then show the other and finally invoke the `gtk.main_quit()` to close your application.